# Searching array kept in NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdictionary

I am having a requirement in which I have 5 keys stored in a NSDictionary corresponding to which I have stored 5 values from different arrays. My data structure looks like:

Dictionary is {

```
1 =     (
                {
            SubRegionName = "abc";
            WalkId = 123;
            WalkName = xyz;
        },
        {
        },....
2 =     (
                {
            SubRegionName = "abc";
            WalkId = 123;
            WalkName = xyz;
        },
        {
        },....
3 =     (
                {
            SubRegionName = "abc;
            WalkId = 123;
            WalkName = xyz;
        },
        {
        },....
4 =     (
                {
            SubRegionName = "abc";
            WalkId = 123;
            WalkName = xyz;
        },
        {
        },....
5 =     (
                {
            SubRegionName = "abc";
            WalkId = 123;
            WalkName = xyz;
        },
        {
        },
        )
```

The above data I am getting from sqlite according to some Id say tempId(1,2,3,4,5) and I want to use them separately. As I have to display the walkName as cell.textlabel.text  and SubregionName as cell.detailtext.text in tableview.

I am not getting how to access this data from the dictionary. Can anyone please suggest me right way to do it.

My code is:

// For Database queries (To get data from database) *********************

```
-(void)getMainRegions
{
    sqlite3 *walkNameDB;
    if (sqlite3_open([[self databasePath] UTF8String], &walkNameDB) != SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_close(walkNameDB);
        NSAssert(0, @"Failed to open Walk name database");
    }



    NSString *regionQuery = @"SELECT Rid,RName from MainRegions";

    sqlite3_stmt *teststatement = nil;

   // NSLog(@"%d",sqlite3_prepare_v2(walkNameDB,[regionQuery UTF8String], -1, &teststatement, nil));

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(walkNameDB,[regionQuery UTF8String], -1, &teststatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        RNameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        RIdArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        while( sqlite3_step(teststatement) == SQLITE_ROW )
        {

            NSNumber *RId;
            int temp1 = (int)sqlite3_column_int(teststatement, 0);
            RId = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:temp1];

            char *RNameCharacter;
            RNameCharacter = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(teststatement, 1);
            NSString *RNameString = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:RNameCharacter];

            [RNameArray addObject:RNameString];
            [RIdArray addObject:RId];


        }

    }
    [self getWalks];
}

-(void)getWalks
{
    sqlite3 *walkNameDB;
    if (sqlite3_open([[self databasePath] UTF8String], &walkNameDB) != SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_close(walkNameDB);
        NSAssert(0, @"Failed to open Walk name database");
    }

    RegionWalksDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    for(regionId in RIdArray)
    {
        regionWalkArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSString *walkQuery = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"SELECT Wid,WName,SName from Walks,SubRegions WHERE Walks.Sid=SubRegions.Sid AND Rid = %d",[regionId integerValue] ];

        sqlite3_stmt *walkstatement = nil;

     //   NSLog(@"%d",sqlite3_prepare_v2(walkNameDB,[walkQuery UTF8String], -1, &walkstatement, nil));

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(walkNameDB,[walkQuery UTF8String], -1, &walkstatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            while( sqlite3_step(walkstatement) == SQLITE_ROW )
            {
                NSNumber *WId;
                int temp1 = (int)sqlite3_column_int(walkstatement, 0);
                WId = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:temp1];

                char *WNameCharacter;
                WNameCharacter = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(walkstatement, 1);
                NSString *WNameString = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:WNameCharacter];

                char *SNameCharacter;
                SNameCharacter = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(walkstatement, 2);
                NSString *SNameString = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:SNameCharacter];

                NSMutableDictionary *tempWalk = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                [tempWalk setObject:WId forKey:@"WalkId"];
                [tempWalk setObject:WNameString forKey:@"WalkName"];
                [tempWalk setObject:SNameString forKey:@"SubRegionName"];
                [regionWalkArray addObject:tempWalk];
            }
        }


        [RegionWalksDictionary setObject:regionWalkArray forKey:regionId];
     //   NSLog(@"arr%@",RegionWalksDictionary);

    }

}
```

//*********  Methods to get data from database ends here **************************

Comment: @ashu there is no array, only a dict with keys

Comment: @Daij-Djan after my edditing I think you may get that the structure is -- Dictionary - array - dictionary.

Comment: @Daij-Djan [regionWalkArray addObject:tempWalk];[RegionWalksDictionary setObject:regionWalkArray forKey:regionId]; you can see this lines for your confusion in the code I posted above.

Comment: Please print the entire dictionary nslog here, As I can see only opening ( and no closing, is 2 inside 1, and 3 inside 2, 4 inside 3 etc???

Comment: ah 5 arrays, each 1 long - didnt see / expect that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way...

```
for(id dict in RegionWalksDictionary){

        NSLog(@"WalkId: %@",[[[RegionWalksDictionary objectForKey:dict]objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"WalkId"] );
        NSLog(@"WalkName: %@",[[[RegionWalksDictionary objectForKey:dict]objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"WalkName"] );
        NSLog(@"SubRegionName: %@",[[[RegionWalksDictionary objectForKey:dict]objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"SubRegionName"] );
        NSLog(@"----");

}
```

---

I have used as following (comment if this is not the structure or your data)

```
NSMutableDictionary *RegionWalksDictionary=[NSMutableDictionary new];
NSMutableArray *regionWalkArray=[NSMutableArray new];
NSMutableDictionary *tempWalk=[NSMutableDictionary new];

[tempWalk setObject:@"wk1" forKey:@"WalkId"];
[tempWalk setObject:@"wkName1" forKey:@"WalkName"];
[tempWalk setObject:@"srName1" forKey:@"SubRegionName"];

[regionWalkArray addObject:tempWalk];

[RegionWalksDictionary setObject:regionWalkArray forKey:@"1"];
[RegionWalksDictionary setObject:regionWalkArray forKey:@"2"];
[RegionWalksDictionary setObject:regionWalkArray forKey:@"3"];

NSLog(@"tempWalkd dict is %@",RegionWalksDictionary);
```

Comment: Thanx for your help but sorry to say that it does'nt worked for me.

Comment: Clear me yaar.. RegionWalksDictionary contains regionalWalkArray and
regionalWalkArray contains tempWalk(dictionary)?

Comment: yes you are right and I want to display walkName and Subregion Name on the cells of tableview..:)

Comment: Thanx this helped me to find solution.

Comment: oh...u donthave 15 points... let me help you..+1 from my side :)

Comment: @Annop I have'nt done any down vote for this. But jst chill I have upvoted it..:)

Comment: @Ashu : Few ba**** are here, they downvote without any comment. If they feel answer is wrong, atleast give reason so that we can understand.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have an `NSDictionary` with your 5 keys, and inside that you have an `NSArray` with a single element that is a `NSDictionary`. Although I might be wrong, try this:

```
NSDictionary *dictionaryForKey1 = [[myDictionary objectForKey:@"1"] objectAtIndex:0];
```

You can then use this:

```
NSString *walkName = [dictionaryForKey1 objectForKey:@"WalkName"];
```

Comment: Thanx for your help but in array I am not having single element but it consist of another dictionary with the 3 elements as I have posted named WalkName,WalkId,SubRegionName, and I want to access those separately.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
NSString * walkName = [[parentDic objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row]] objectForKey:@"WalkName"];
NSString * SubregionName = [[parentDic objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row]] objectForKey:@"SubRegionName"];
```

Comment: Thanx but it is printing null value as their is not such key. The keys are 1,2,3,4and 5 rest are data in the array and the array inturn consist a dictionary in it. I have done so because the data is coming from database.

Comment: @ashu you whish -- there is no array

Comment: Then modify the code as
NSArray *dataArray = [parentDic objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row]];
NSDictionary *cellDict = [dataArray objectAtIndex:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row]];
NSString * walkName = [cellDict objectForKey:@"WalkName"];
NSString * SubregionName =  [cellDict objectForKey:@"SubRegionName"];
Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

AH! now I see it -- there are 5 arrays of length 1

```
NSArray *array1 = dict[@"1];
NSDictionary *details = array1[0];

//print each var
id WalkName = details[@"WalkName"];
```